# packaging wearable app in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, export, packaging, wear-os

I have read all posts that developers page(https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html) about packaging wear.

I've tryed step by step everything and nothing works, the wear app never gets installed on the watch. APK installed on my phone, but not in my watch. They have the same package name, permissions, versionCode and versionName.
Each app works well!

I debugged local host:4444, (computer and phone connected via USB connecter, bluetooth connected phone and watch) in eclipse.

**problem**

1. the wear app never gets installed on the watch(usb connect smartphone, debug smartphone application)
2. When I bluetooth debuging an app for smart phones, occurs an error.(usb connect smartphone and wear connect bluetooth debug, debug smartphone application)

why don't installed my watch application? how to solve problem? and what should I debug that phone app or watch app in local host:4444 via bluetooth? If "Turn off Asset Compression" need to me? help me!

**code**

watch manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.abced.abc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="20"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>"
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>


<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_mark"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:exported="true"
         android:allowEmbedded="true"
         android:taskAffinity=""
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

phone manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.abcde.abc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>"
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_mark"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.wearable.beta.app"
             android:resource="@xml/wear_desc"/>


    <activity
        android:name="com.abcde.abc.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

wear_desc.xml / apk name : abc.apk

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wearableApp package="com.abcde.abc">
  <versionCode>1</versionCode>
  <versionName>1.0</versionName>
  <rawPathResId>abc</rawPathResId> 
</wearableApp>
```

Answer (score 0):

Among many requirements, you **must** have the exact same permissions on both sides, it looks like you forgot `android.permission.WAKE_LOCK` on the phone manifest.

You also need `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />` in the Wear manifest.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I modified my code. but wear app never get in eclipse debugging. (Debugging the phone app is executed, the watch app has not been installed). Is there any other way? If there are only run in the play store?